# Error while getting Full-Bayer-Layer data using Libcamera-raw

Tags: picamera, libcamera

I'm trying to get full bayer layer data of Pi-Camera V2 (NoIR).

I just followed the [official doc](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#libcamera-raw).

```
libcamera-raw -t 2000 --segment 1 -o test%05d.raw
```

Above command produces `.raw` files with each size of 375K. I assume these are `640x480 stride 800 format SBGGR10_CSI2P` as `libcamera-raw` prints when execution.

---

However I want **Full Raw Bayer** layer data. So I tried following command, and got error: `Not enough buffers provided by V4L2VideoDevice`:

```
$ libcamera-raw -t 2000 --segment 1 --width 3280 --height 2464  -o test%05d.raw

WARNING: consider inline headers with 'pause'/split/segment/circular
[0:24:31.109879383] [4103]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:299 libcamera v0.0.2+47-0684c373
[0:24:31.150202004] [4104]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1306 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:24:31.151336340] [4104]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1423 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media2 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:24:31.152473175] [4103]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1026 configuring streams: (0) 3280x2464-YUV420 (1) 3280x2464-SBGGR10_CSI2P
[0:24:31.152877504] [4104]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:803 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 3280x2464-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 3280x2464-pBAA
[0:24:31.176509978] [4104] ERROR V4L2 v4l2_videodevice.cpp:1248 /dev/video14[14:cap]: Not enough buffers provided by V4L2VideoDevice
ERROR: *** failed to allocate capture buffers ***
```

---

How to get full 3280x2464 10bit bayer layer data in new`libcamera-apps`?

---

System info:

- Board: Pi4B, 4Gb
- OS: Raspberry Pi OS (64bit) lite.
- GPU mem: 256Mb (`$vcgencmd get_mem gpu` shows `gpu=256M`)

Comment: Have you done any research in this matter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, @MatsK,  **How to get full 3280x2464 10bit bayer layer data in newlibcamera-apps?** This is my question.

Comment: And you didn't answer mine!